# How can I read the Active Directory schema programmatically

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I did some programming for reading the data from Active Directory such as user account or Orgnization info and so on. The code below is like something what I did.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com",
    null,
    null,
    AuthenticationTypes.Secure
    );

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

using (SearchResultCollection src = search.FindAll())
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in src)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["name"][0] + " : " + 
                          result.Properties["department"][0]);
    }
}
```

The problem is how can I know what properties that target objects have then I can use them to filter the data before get it all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `DirectoryEntry`, you can inspect its `.SchemaEntry`:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://......");

DirectoryEntry schema = entry.SchemaEntry;
```

This should - if you have the necessary permissions - give you access to the properties defined in the schema - things like `MandatoryProperties` or `OptionalProperties`:

```
foreach (var prop in schema.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
   string propName = prop.ToString();
   var propValue = schema.Properties[propName].Value;
}
```

Does that help you get started??

You might also want to have a look at **[BeaverTail](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html)** - my C# open-source LDAP browser.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mvps.org](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail1.png))</sub>

It will allow you to inspect any LDAP node and see all its properties.

Comment: Both your answer and the LDAP browser are great.

Comment: @marc_s could you please guide me what is the type of `deMyself` in this line `DirectoryEntry schema = deMyself.SchemaEntry;` ?

Comment: @prog1011: it's a typo - it should be `entry` which is of type `DirectoryEntry`